# Escape shell expression in Jenkins file

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am trying to split a version number and store it in an array using a shell script. This works fine in a regular shell environment. However, when I try to implement this in Jenkins file using sh call I have problems escaping //. I tried a couple of other ways and not able to get proper values.

```
orig_ver=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
//This is working in bash shell but not in Jenkins file
next_ver_arr=(${orig_ver//./})
```

Tried to use like below and the escape sequence is not working in Jenkins file.

```
sh '''

orig_ver=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
next_ver_arr=(${orig_ver//./})


'''
```

Alternatively, I tried using below but that's starting to have bugs, which is not giving me the expected results

```
sh '''
orig_ver=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
next_ver_arr=($(echo $orig_ver|tr -d . | cut -d- -f1|sed 's/\\(.\\)/\\1 /g'))
'''
```

Comment: Have you considered doing it in Groovy instead? You can read your pom and get version from there, you can use maven for incrementing version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding the `bash` shebang to your script in the node:

```
node {
    sh '''#!/bin/bash
          orig_ver=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
          next_ver_arr=${orig_ver//./}
          echo $next_ver_arr
    '''
}
```

Comment: Adding she-bang won't do anything usefull for bash, you need it only for interpreter override (i.e you want to use python instead of bash) https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/Shell.java#L86

Comment: @andreoss Is `sh` the same thing as `bash` on all systems?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The major distributions usually have /bin/sh symlinked to /bin/bash. But you have a point